# how to Import MySql Dump file in MySQLWorkBench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL Dump file for few objects of a database and I have to import only one table from that file in MYSQL Work Bench.

My question is 
How can I import a dump file in MySQL Work Bench for specified table or for all tables?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to extract that particular table and then import in to the workbench.

`sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --extract TABLE --match_str table-name`

This will extract your table in "out" folder and then you can import that to the workbench.

Source: [MySQLDumpSplitter](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/how-to-recipes-for-mysqldumpsplitter)